# Positive negation in Java

Tags: java, binary, negation

How to make that after the negation operation, i.e. ~ 10 (binary: 1010), the result would not be -11 but 5, 10 = binary 1010 and after negation 0101 or 5.
Thank you for help!

Comment: You are mistaken, `~` is not a "negation operation". Java has the [`-` (Unary Minus Operator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4), which performs a negation of numeric values, as well as the [`~` (Bitwise Complement Operator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.5) and the [`!` (Logical Complement Operator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.6), neither of which does "negation".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binary representation of 10 is not 1010, it's 000...0001010 (with total of 32 bits).

Therefore the negation is 111...1110101, which is -11.

If you want to get 5, you need to keep only the least significant 4 bits (and reset all the rest to `0`):

```
int x = 10;
System.out.println (~x & 0xf);
```

For a more general solution, if you want to negate only the `n` least significant bits (where `n-1` is the index of the highest `1` bit in the input number) and keep all the higher bits `0`, you can use Lino's suggestion:

```
System.out.println (~x & ((Integer.highestOneBit(x) << 1) - 1));
```

Comment: the mask (`0xf`) could probably be dynamically computed using `(Integer.highestOneBit(x) << 1) - 1`

Comment: Well yea ... but the OP is "specifying by example", and Eran's solution meets the specification :-)

Comment: @Lino good suggestion